# regex or replace() with wildcard?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string:

`a (45:45) b (65:40) ccc (blah$#)`

I want to remove everything that are inside the `()`, including the `()` to look like this:

`a b ccc`

I was going to try to wrestle with `re` but thought maybe it could be done with a wildcard and `replace()`. I want to avoid `re` if possible.

Comment: what do you want to do with the whitespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `re` to use wildcards. I mean, you could parse the string out manually, but that seems like a huge waste of time.

```
import re

s = 'a (45:45) b (65:40) ccc (blah$#)'
print re.sub('\s?\(.*?\)', '', s).strip() # 'a b ccc'
```

Comment: Halfway decent, but will fail when `s` starts with a group in parens.

Comment: @hop Removed the first matching so the string can start with a group. The output might start with a space, but I don't have time right now to iron that out.

Answer (score 1):

You are right: regular expressions should not always be the first tool that comes to mind when parsing strings, especially when there might potentially be nested structures involved.

It is relatively easy to count the parentheses and act accordingly:

```
def filter_parens(sentence):
    result, level = [], 0
    for c in sentence:
        if c == '(':
            level += 1
        elif c == ')':
            level = max(0, level-1)
        elif level == 0:
            result.append(c)
    return ''.join(result)
```

With a bit of imagination you can extend it to elminate brackets or runs of whitespace as well:

```
def filter_parens(sentence):
    result, level, whitespace = [], 0, False
    for c in sentence:
        if c == '(':
            level += 1
            continue

        if c == ')':
            level = max(0, level-1)
            continue

        if level:
            continue

        if c.isspace() and not whitespace:
            whitespace = True
            result.append(c)
            continue

        if c.isspace():
            continue

        whitespace = False
        result.append(c)

    return ''.join(result)
```

Comment: This is a fine solution *if* there are nested structures involved. But, it might be worth mentioning that this is overkill in the situations where a one line regex would suffice.

Comment: Well, the other answers here don't inspire much confidence in regex solutions. Also, The OP asked for it.